# ¿Cómo usar los valores de un ArrayList de un método en otro método?

Tags: java, variables, clase, método

Quisiera saber si se pueden usar las variables de un método en otro método, es decir, yo tengo el siguiente código.

```
private class Lista {

    private String Lista() {
        List<String> p = new ArrayList<>();
        p.add("brócoli");
        p.add("círculo");
        p.add("célula");
        p.add("carátula");
        p.add("depósito");
        p.add("física");
        p.add("ábaco");
        p.add("azúcar");
        p.add("ámbar");
        p.add("ángel");
        p.add("César");
        p.add("césped");
        p.add("cádiz");
        p.add("éter");
        p.add("bebé");
        p.add("acción");
        p.add("avión");
        p.add("Jesús");
        p.add("país");
        p.add("papá");
        p.add("sofá");

        return null;
    }
}
```

Y quiero usar la variable "p" en el siguiente método

```
private class Correcto {

        private String Correcto() {
            Lista l = new Lista();

            coi.setText("¡Es correcto!");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Has declarado la variable de forma local. Si quieres que las variables puedan usarse en más de un método de una misma clase tienes que declararlas de forma global:

```
    List<String> p;

    private String Lista() {
    p = new ArrayList<>();
    p.add("brócoli");
    p.add("círculo");
    p.add("célula");
    p.add("carátula");
    p.add("depósito");
    p.add("física");
    p.add("ábaco");
    p.add("azúcar");
    p.add("ámbar");
    p.add("ángel");
    p.add("César");
    p.add("césped");
    p.add("cádiz");
    p.add("éter");
    p.add("bebé");
    p.add("acción");
    p.add("avión");
    p.add("Jesús");
    p.add("país");
    p.add("papá");
    p.add("sofá");

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes retornar tu 'ArrayList' en tu metodo lista e invocarlo en tu metodo 'Correcto' 
Te dejo un ejemplo.

```
public class Correcto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Lista l = new Lista();

        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println(l.lista());
    }

    private static class Lista {

        private ArrayList lista(){
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            list.add("Hola");
            list.add("Mundo");
            return list;
        }

        ;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu método crea una lista de elementos que deseas utilizar en otro método, por lo tanto debes retornar la lista al llamar el método, cambia el tipo a List y retorna la lista:

```
  //private String Lista() {
   private List Lista() {
        List<String> p = new ArrayList<>();
        p.add("brócoli");
        p.add("círculo");
        p.add("célula");
        p.add("carátula");
        p.add("depósito");
        p.add("física");
        p.add("ábaco");
        p.add("azúcar");
        p.add("ámbar");
        p.add("ángel");
        p.add("César");
        p.add("césped");
        p.add("cádiz");
        p.add("éter");
        p.add("bebé");
        p.add("acción");
        p.add("avión");
        p.add("Jesús");
        p.add("país");
        p.add("papá");
        p.add("sofá");

        //return null;
         return p;

    }
```

> Y quiero usar la variable "p" en el siguiente método
>   Llama el método y obtendrás sus valores:

```
   Lista l = new Lista();
  //Llama el método.
   List p = l.Lista();
```

Esta sería la llamada del método en la clase `Correcto` para realizar la comparación de cadenas:

```
private class Correcto {

  private String Correcto() {
     Lista l = new Lista();
     List p = l.Lista();

     for(int i = 0; i< p.size();i++){
       String cadena  = (String)p.get(i);
         if(cadena.equals("bebé")){
           coi.setText("¡Es correcto!"); 
         } 
     }            
        return null;
  }
}
```